# Drupal Clean URLs Enabled; still have ?q= in links

Tags: drupal, clean-urls

I've enabled clean URLs on my Drupal 7 website, however they don't seem to be working properly.

Example: I can visit http://url.com/store without issue. However, if I click it in my site navigation, it navigates to http://url.com/?q=store (the same goes for all site links).

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How did you make your site navigation? Using the core *Menu* module or with some other way?

Comment: Yes, I used the core menu module. Unfortunately this isn't an issue with the site's navigation only - all internal links (for example, products in the store linking to a single product page) contain the ?q= in the url.

Comment: I've found the solution should anyone come across the same issue. Despite enabling clean urls, they were still disabled in my settings.php file.
    `$conf = array(
        'clean_url' => 1,
    );`
Modifying this code does the trick (it can also be changed to 0 if you for some reason need to disable clean-urls). This can also be done in the database, however modifying settings.php is easiest.

Comment: You could add this as an answer to own your question and accept it, CodeMonkey13.

Comment: Thanks, unor. I'm still new to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution should anyone come across the same issue. Despite enabling clean URLs, they were still disabled in my settings.php file.

```
$conf = array(     
    'clean_url' => 1,     
);
```

Modifying this code does the trick (it can also be changed to `0` if you for some reason need to disable clean URLs). This can also be done in the database, however modifying settings.php is easiest.